# sql insert- 1 big query, or many single queries

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, insert, odbc

I am using PHP with an odbc connection to MSSQL database.

Currently, I having around 1900 insert statements, in the one string, separated by a semicolon, and running that in 1 odbc_execute statement.

Firstly, is this a bad method? Should I be processing every insert statement separately in a for loop?

Also, the way I am currently doing it, with 1 big statement, for some reason, only a maximum of 483 rows are being inserted with no errors. If I copy the statement that is run and run this through SQL studio, all rows insert, yet every single time, only a maximum of 483 rows insert.
Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One network round trip per INSERT will mean a lot of latency.  It'll be very slow.

There's probably a limit on the buffer size of all those concatenated SQL statements.

I think you want to use a prepared statement and bound variables:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712553(v=vs.85).aspx

You can still process it in a loop - two, actually.  You'll want an inner loop to add INSERTs to a batch that's executed as a single transaction, and an outer loop to process all the necessary batches.

Comment: So is this the same as basically saying put every 100 rows into an array, then loop over that array performing the same odbc_execute statement?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you aren't running a separate transaction for each insert, there's nothing wrong with inserting one at a time.

For this sort of 'batch insert' I would typically run a transaction for every 100 rows or so.

I would avoid trying to cram them all in at once. nothing really to be gained by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You may put the data in a file (xml?) on the sql-server and request a stored procedure from php that process it.

regards,
/t